# Address of a class member without a class instance?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, member

I occasionally see bits of code similar to this:

```
class A {
    int b;
}

void foo() {
    int* blah = &A::b;
    // Other stuff.
}
```

But how could grabbing the address of a class' member variable without an instance of the class be useful? What does it do?

Comment: Are you sure `b` isn't a static member of `A`?

Comment: I'm sure. I've seen bits of code where it seemed to rely on it not being a static member.

Comment: In that case, are you sure the type of `blah` is `int*`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is ill-formed and will not compile.  The type of `blah` is not `int*`, it is `int (A::*)`.  That is, it is not a "pointer to an `int`," it is a "pointer to a data member of class type `A` whose type is `int`."

Note that in order to obtain a pointer to a member, the member must be accessible.  To compute `&A::b` in `foo()`, `b` would need to be a public data member, or `foo()` would need to be a friend of `A`.

A pointer-to-member does not point to an object.  Rather, a pointer-to-member can be bound to an object to get the value of its data member.  You can obtain the value of the `b` data member of an `A` object by binding the `blah` pointer-to-member to the instance of `A`.  For example,

```
A x;
int b_value = x.*blah; // b_value has the value of x.b
```

Comment: That... makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The class `A` has int `b`. That mean `b` is data of class `A`, you can get pointer to `b` if you have an instance of `A`.

I think you want to ask for this case:

```
class A{
   int foo(int i) {
   }
}
```

after compiled,the method foo has address, you can get pointer to `&A::foo`.